# How can I determine statistically how well my estimator predicts actual results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit

I have a business in which I contract with my clients to perform work for them for an indefinite amount of time.  To forecast my profitability, I need to forecast when my existing contracts will end.  I have historical data from which I made a simple function to estimate the likelihood that a contract ends as a function of the age of the contract (how many weeks the contract has been active).  This runoff function is a simple table

| Age in weeks | % of remaining contracts that end (Runoff %) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9.26% |
| 2 | 7.34% |
| 3 | 5.23% |
| ... | ... |
| 208 | 1.25% |

I then take each contract and look up its expected Runoff % for the next week and sum those %'s to get the total number of contracts expected to end.  I continue this process for each week in the forecast (increasing each contracts age by 1 as the weeks move forward).

To test whether this is a good estimator, I have looked at forecasting just 1 week into the future.  Thus I estimate next week's number of contracts that will end and compare that to the actual number of contracts that ended.

| Week | Estimate | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-4 | 105 | 97 |
| Jan-11 | 106 | 111 |
| Jan-18 | 106 | 107 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Dec-27 | 146 | 152 |

What statistical test should I run to determine whether the estimator is a good one and at what confidence level?

I looked at chi-square tests, but they look to apply to categorical data and so does not appear to apply here.

Comment: It all depends on what "good" means in your application.  Why would you need a test?  Don't you just want to *measure* how accurate the estimates are?

Comment: There are various tests for comparing different forecasts for the same actuals, like the Diebold-Mariano test, so you could test whether your forecast is better than some benchmark, like a naive historical average. But as @whuber writes, you will usually just calculate the error of your forecasts and decide whether they are good enough for any decisions you want to base on them.

Comment: My sense of "good" is meant to determine whether I need to search for a new estimator.  When I looked at the chi-square test, I wanted to be able to say the estimator results and the actual results are likely drawn from the same distribution at a 95% confidence interval.  I ran a linear regression with the actuals as the dependent variable and the estimate as the independent.  R-squared was 99% and coefficient was 0.998.  That seems very good to me, but I would like to make statement regarding confidence intervals if possible.

Comment: An additional consideration for the statistics is I am concerned the distribution changes through time - COVID could certainly have changed client behaviour.